# Localize strings in XAML UI in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, windows-10-universal

I have a resource entry named `info_278` in the `Resources.resw` file on my UWP app. I have 3 scenarios where I need to use this resource but looks like I need to duplicate this to cater to different scenarios. Scenarios are as follows.

1. Error message content from code

   `var displayErrorOnPopup = ResourceHandler.Get("info_278");`
2. TextBlock Text property from XAML (Looks like a new entry needed as **info_278.Text**)

   `<TextBlock x:Uid="info_278" Margin="10,0,0,0" />`
3. Button Content property from XAML (Looks like a new entry needed as **info_278.Content**)

   `<Button x:Uid="info_278" Margin="10,0,0,0" />`

How do I proceed without duplicating this resource in the `.resw` file?

---

[image]

Comment: do you want to avoid duplication of "info_278" string?

Comment: Yes. If cant I like to know what are my options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to avoid duplication is to set the string value in code-behind using [ResourceLoader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader?view=winrt-22000). Because you could direct access to the specific property of the target control. Like  this:

```
var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
this.TextBlock.Text = resourceLoader.GetString("info_278");
```

If you are not going to do it in the code behind, then I have to say there is no way to avoid the duplication of the resource string. You should add **info_278.Text** and **info_278.Content** for different XAML scenarios.

Comment: Could you explain further under the "Note" section of this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#refer-to-a-string-resource-identifier-from-xaml

Comment: @SurenSaluka Which note part do you mean? The red note part? or the Note part above?

Comment: I quote "Note For attached properties, you need a special syntax in the"... This part. Love to see an example of the usage of attached properties with localization.

Comment: @SurenSaluka I have to say that I haven't used localization for attached properties before. So I can't share an example of this.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a markup extension. I've used this in WinUI 3, but should work in UWP too.

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;

namespace MyApp;

[MarkupExtensionReturnType(ReturnType = typeof(string))]
public class StringResourceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private static readonly ResourceLoader _resourceLoader = new();

    public StringResourceExtension() { }

    public string Key { get; set; } = "";

    protected override object ProvideValue()
    {
        return _resourceLoader.GetString(Key);
    }
}
```

Then in the XAML:

```
...
local="using:MyApp"
...

<TextBlock Text="{local:StringResource Key=info_278}" />
<Button Content="{local:StringResource Key=info_278}" />
```